# Rails3 nested_form is not really clear

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I try to do something nice with the nested_form gem in rails3. (I could not use this gem but it looks like rails3 always need a gem to do this things... And Google always redirects me to this gem for nested forms in rails3)

So I have this achitecture:

- Model1 has_many Model2 (, :dependent => :nullify)
- Model1 has_many Model3 (, :dependent => :nullify)
- Model2 belongs_to Model1
- Model2 belongs_to Model3

  - accepts_nested_attributes_for :model3, :limit => 1
  - attr_accessible :model3_attributes
- Model3 has_many Model2
- Model3 belongs_to Model1

The idea, in the backoffice, is to create a Model1, then create a nested Model2, and in the creation form of the Model2, select in a list or create a new Model3.

I scaffolded a lot of things, and now I am looking the documentation about how to do that, but I need help because rails3 "guesses" everything, so I feel like I add stuff without real tutorial or example instead of doing the right thing.

#### Currently:

1. Everything works if I have some Model3 created. here is my Model2 form: http://pastebin.com/6te9fSK8 (they appear in the list and I select them)
2. Now I wanted to have the "new model3" feature. So I added the nested_form gem
3. I added this code http://pastebin.com/nzqVzwzn
4. First, in the case of an edit, it "works": I can create a new model3 and it will be added in the list and will replace the previous.
5. But, after review, each time I want to add a new one, it replace the old one I added. I looks like a JavaScript problem (I am using jQuery9)
6. If I create a new model1 then a nested model2, the model3 list is empty. So even if I add a new model3 with the new field, the form expect I select a model3 from the (empty) list. Even if I remove the list from the form it is still waiting I select a model3 and doesn't care about my new model3 I added. (I could bypass that by create a default model3 when I create a new model1 but it looks like a weak patch...)

I didn't touch to my controllers except the model2 where I added a protected method to find the @model1 from :model1_id

```
  class Models2Controller < ApplicationController
      before_filter :get_model1

      ...
      protected
      def get_model1
        @model1 = Model1.find(params[:model1_id])
      end
```

If anybody can help me on how to manage this properly, it will be really helpful.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

That is a very long question that will take a very long answer. I would suggest you go watch [196 Nested Model Form part1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1), [197 Nested Model Form part2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2) and maybe a [few more](http://railscasts.com/?search=nested%20form&type=free&utf8=%E2%9C%93), such as the Complex form ones.

Generally you can have any model create an instance of any other model by having `accepts_nested_attributes_for :model` in your models. So Model1 would accept for Model2 and Model2 would accept for Model3. In your Model2 (I know it feels like you want to put this in the controller, but don't) you can have a factory method that will check if it got a id for a Model3 instance or if it got attributes for a new Model3 and create it as needed...

The screencasts above will show you the way when it comes to the form hierarchy and the only part you need to edit for your situation is that the last step is either a new model or an existing one, but that is not what you are having trouble with anyway :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I need to pay to access to the answer. I finally did it with some Ajax:

I added when the page is ready, 2 options to my select fields, a disabled "-----" then "add". When the user select the "add", it ask a name, send a ajax post on a route to add the new model3 and return the id. Then I add the model3 name+id to the option before the "---".

It works...

Comment: My bad. Filtering on railscasts.com was not addative. I have edited the answer to link to the free episodes instead.